# Why broadcast to specific IDs wont work if in a loop

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have 3 types of users: nonmods, mods and admins. I want to emit an event with different values accordingly so I did this:

```
   socket.broadcast.to(admins).emit('login', {
    onlineusers: usersadmin
   });

   socket.broadcast.to(mods).emit('login', {
    onlineusers: usersmod
   });

   socket.broadcast.to(nonmods).emit('login', {
    onlineusers: usersnonmod
   });
```

that works fine but its kinda redundant so in order to save code I tried this:

```
  let roles = {nonmods : usersnonmod, mods : usersmod, admins : usersadmin}
  
  for(let rolename in roles) {
   socket.broadcast.to(rolename).emit('login', {
    onlineusers: roles[rolename]
   });
```

however it wont broadcast to any user at all like this. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use arrays as keys for objects, that is why it doesn't work. Also in your current example you just set keys `admins`, `mods` and `nonmods` as strings, you are not using the actual variable value.

If you want to use some kind of storage that can use anything as a key, you can use `Map`

```
const map = new Map();

map.set(admins, usersadmin);
map.set(mods, usersmod);
map.set(nonmods, usersnonmod);

for (const [rooms, users] of map.entries()) {
   socket.broadcast.to(rooms).emit('login', {
    onlineusers: users
   });
}
```

I would not do that personally. The original code does what it should be doing. It is not redundant, it just doing what is required. The code is DRY while the knowledge has a single representation in the system.

Comment: yes, they are variables. I tried your code but it still wont work.  Could you please post the full code? Maybe Im still missing something.

Comment: it works if I do this: `dumb = rolename = admins ? admins : rolename = mods ? mods : nonmods;
       socket.broadcast.to(dumb).emit('login', {` but I find it really dumb.

Comment: What are these values? nonmods mods admins?

Comment: they are socket.ids from the logged members. If a member is an admin then its socket.id will be added into admins and so on.

Comment: I have updated the answer. See it again.

Comment: Great approach, seems to work right. Thanks. Only one issue, seems like if the role has no users in it then the socket will emit to all users. I tried by wrapping the emit function inside `if(roles != null)` but didnt work. Any ideas?

Comment: nevermind, it works now with `if(roles != "")`. Thank you!